# NHibernate transaction deadlock when two processes access the database

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, transactions, deadlock

I have two processes that access the same database tables concurrently.
Both processes use NHibernate-3.2.0.
One process deletes rows and another inserts rows to the same tables.
When two processes works in parallel I am getting the deadlock error in the "INSERT" process.

*[ERROR] TID:6 NHibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - Transaction (Process ID 64) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.*

The insert performed as session.Save(obj) inside the transaction.
The object id has Guid type and the generator class is "guid.comb".

It seems like afterward the NHibernate tries to handle this situation performing several attempts to insert the row. In the NHibernate sql log file I see number of INSERT statements to the same table with the  with THE SAME ID.

And the following is the next error:
*[ERROR] TID:6 Hibernate.Util.ADOExceptionReporter - Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint.*

Questions:

1. Is it possible to prevent deadlock situations in my scenarion by the
   NHibernate abilites?
2. Is it possible to prevent from NHibernate to
       perform several attempt to insert the row and handle the problem in
       my code (outside NHibernate)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both processes using the same NHSession? Are you using transactions? When do you Commit or Flush?

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock occurs when two or more processes are all waiting for access to resources already held by the other process. To prevent deadlock, you must ensure that at least one process will always be able to continue. One strategy to ensure that is to order your locks. If both processes always grab locks in the same order, deadlock cannot occur because if a process succeeds in grabbing the first lock, it means that the second lock must be free (or held by something which won't require the first lock and therefore will not need to wait for that lock to be released).

One way to achieve that is to have both processes grab table locks. You can also analyse the processes in SQL server to find what locks they grab and what they are waiting for.

As for the second part, I doubt that NHibernate itself is retrying the INSERT statement. Are you following the required practice of immediately rolling back and discard the transaction and NHibernate session in which the exception occurred?